# validation for select option not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I doing a form for a small project, and having a trouble trying to validate the select option
hope someone can help

THanks in advance

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="vehicleform" action=" " onSubmit="return (validateForm())">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
Phone Number <font size="1px">(ex. 123-456-7890)</font>: <input type="text" name="phonenumber"><br>
Location 
<select name="location">
  <option value="-1">Select one..</option>
  <option value="lota">Lot A</option>
  <option value="lotb">Lot B</option>
  <option value="lotc">Lot C</option>
</select><br>
```

JS:

```
function validateForm(){

  var d = document.forms['vehicleform']['location'].value;

  if( document.vehicleform.location.value == "-1" )
  {
    alert("Please select your location");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: the variable d already contains the value so all you need to do is if( d == -1 ) { .... }

Comment: @jeff still having the problem

Comment: Don't you need to declare the first option (with the value -1) as selected for your JS validation to catch if it is not answered properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/LVBSZ/1/

You have no submit button in your code and close tag for form. The other works for me

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        if (document.forms['vehicleform'].location.value == "-1") {
            alert("Please select your location");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<form method="post" name="vehicleform" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
    First Name:
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <br>Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="lname">
    <br>Phone Number <font size="1px">(ex. 123-456-7890)</font>:
    <input type="text" name="phonenumber">
    <br>Location
    <select name="location">
        <option value="-1">Select one..</option>
        <option value="lota">Lot A</option>
        <option value="lotb">Lot B</option>
        <option value="lotc">Lot C</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for grouping in the listener, and passing *this* gives immediate access to the form:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
```

You only need to check the selected index to see if something other than the first option (or no option all) is selected:

```
function validateForm(form) {

  if (form.location.selectedIndex < 1) {
    alert("Please select your location");
    return false;
  }
}
```

And as suggested in the comments, make the first option selected by default:

```
<select name="location">
  <option value="-1" selected>Select one..
  <option value="lota">Lot A
```

as browsers may not make any option selected by default and users won't see "Select one...". That should be a label anyway to assist with accessiblity.